# Shadow options are not showing

Tags: lighting, shadows

[image]I am using the latest blender version but as i was trying to change the softness and exponent of my lamp shadows there was no option. It only showed the clip start and Bias. Any way i can bring these options back
[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome! Can you use the question editor to add (image tool) a screenshot showing the Properties panel where this is happening? Which rendering engine are you using?

Comment: i just updated the question and attached a screenshot but i am new to blender and dont know how to check what render engine i am using

Comment: See my updated answer: those options are gone since 2.81, but you have alternatives to follow tutorials that use older versions...

Answer (score 1):

I think the youtube video you are referring to, in commenting another answer, was realized using an older version of blender. I tried an old 2.80 I had installed, and it shows the options you're missing (they're missing in my 2.82a, too):

[image]

Those options are gone in 2.81. This release log (related to python API usage of those options) points this out and cites a developer change in code_ https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.81/Python_API#EEVEE

Anyway it is always possible to download any previous version as a zip package, and just extract them in a folder and run them launching the blender file. You find all released versions here: https://download.blender.org/release/

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The features you want--Clip Start and Bias--are visible in the Object Data tab of the Properties Panel while your light is selected, under the Shadow menu. If you can't see them, the Shadow menu header may need to be expanded. (Please disregard my colorless tabs. They are the same tabs as your much more colorful ones, only mine are much less exciting)

[image]

The current rendering engine is visible from the Render Properties tab of the Properties Panel, in a pull down menu near the top.

Comment: no thats not what im looking for i attached an image from a youtube video where there are options on his that are not on mine and we are using the same version of blender

Comment: My apologies. I do now see that you have added another image.